# Fabric.js conflict with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have website on Ruby on Rails 3.2.11 and JQuery 1.11.1.
I have included the library Fabric.js. After that, most of the functions JQuery (event click, on, change, etc.) stopped working.
Please help me, how to implement the joint work JQuery and Fabric.js libraries? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is conflicting js files problem here,try using `$.noConflict()` when different js files conflict with one another.

see here :- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Example :-

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, but, I do not even use the code of another library.
I just add the library Fabric.js, and JQuery does not operate properly.

Comment: @sanyasobolev...strange ..check use only single version of jquery and visit this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537200/how-do-i-avoid-this-jquery-files-conflict